# Stop button functionality in serial port data form makes it unresponsive

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, serial-port, arduino

In my forms application,I'm reading serial data using a serial port and storing them in a list for further use. I have a stop button event but on clicking the button the form doesn't terminate.The form contains textboxes which display the parsed values obtained from the Serial Port(the parsing process gets initiated by clicking a button called Start). My objective is to pause the receiving of data from the serial port when the Stop button is pressed. As of now when the Start button is clicked, the data reading begins, but for some reason the Stop button doesn't function.

```
private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        serialPort1.NewLine = "-";
        RxString = serialPort1.ReadLine();
        RxString = RxString.Replace("$", "");

        this.Invoke(new EventHandler(DisplayText));

    }
    private void DisplayText(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        richTextBox1.AppendText(RxString);
        GlobalList.AddRange(parsed());


        displayglobal();
        graphs();
    }
    private void Start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        serialPort1.PortName = "COM32";
        serialPort1.BaudRate = 9600;
        serialPort1.DtrEnable = true;
        serialPort1.Open();
        if (serialPort1.IsOpen)
        {
            Start.Enabled = false;
            Stop.Enabled = true;
            richTextBox1.ReadOnly = false;

        }

    }

    private void Stop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (serialPort1.IsOpen)
        {
            serialPort1.Close();
            Start.Enabled = true;
            Stop.Enabled = false;
            richTextBox1.ReadOnly = true;



        }
```

Comment: The try catch block can be used and it will catch exceptions, but my problem is that when the Stop button is clicked I need the data to stop being read from the Serial Port. I mainly think it is because the input buffer doesn't get cleared and as Hans Passant mentioned in his answer( which seems to have been deleted) there is a deadlock.

Answer (score 0):

What i usually do, instead of abruptly closing the serial port, is to put a checking before the readline.
Say, your status of ON or OFF. And change the status from outside the event receive.
The event receive is always fire whenever the data is available in the buffer. 
1. When data is available, event receive is fire
2. Create a condition if the status is ON, execute readline, otherwise ignore readline.
3. Put set status OFF in your Stop button and ON in your Start button.
4. Whenever you think you dont need the comm, you then can close it.

Hope this help.